# How to create custom turtle shapes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a turtle with a png photo as its shape.
I have tried using this method:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

image = ("rocketship.png")

screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
```

but then it shows this:

````
  File "C:\Users\Drukker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Among_us.py", line 10, in <module>
    screen.addshape(image)
  File "C:\Users\Drukker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1136, in register_shape
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("Bad arguments for register_shape.\n"
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: Bad arguments for register_shape.
Use  help(register_shape)```

Does anyone know a solution?
Thanks
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just two days ago and you have to convert your png to a gif. A good site for this is https://ezgif.com/apng-to-gif. If you download it and save it, you have to find it in the computer, using the code... Here is what I did:

```
import os
from turtle import *
sc = Screen()
sc.setup(600,600)
image = os.path.expanduser("~\OneDrive\Desktop\AlienGameImage.gif")
sc.addshape(image)
t = Turtle()
t.shape(image)
mainloop()
```

The reason `raise TurtleGraphicsError("Bad arguments for register_shape.\n"` comes up is because it does not accept a PNG image to register it as a shape.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `.addshape()` method.

If it's not a `gif` file, you have to specify `shape` attribute.

See details here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.addshape

Comment: Can you explain more?